# call window.onbeforeunload on link button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having tab interface on the page. In tab I am having link button. If there are changes on the page which are not saved to the database then I want to cancel tab change and show the message there are changes on  the page. Can I achive this by calling window.onbeforeunload ? Is that possible to call window.onbeforeunload on link button click? How can I achieve this?

Can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the beforeunload event with jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');
});
```

The unload event should also work.